Error code 0x8007000d for any .NET IIS web app on an EC2
I'm trying to learn deployment of .NET web apps on Amazon EC2. I've created a template Blazor Server project targeting .NET7, published it in Release mode to a folder. After that, I uploaded all the files to a folder in my free-tier EC2 Windows Server 2022 Datacenter instance (21H2).
I've got IIS installed and running. I've stopped the default site and added a new site with the Physical path pointing to the folder where my published website files are. The port for the site is 8080.
When I'm starting the site and trying to browse on the same EC2 machine I get this error:
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
Error code: 0x8007000d

I've tried a few solution I found online (changing access permissions, installing support for .NET Framework in IIS) but nothing worked. I also tried uploading some other web apps I have (.NET8) but they got the same error too.
What is the real problem here and what's the solution?
